# C# -SharePoint - SPGridView - Grouping

Tags: sharepoint, spgridview

I have enabled grouping in my SPGridView. If the records in the grouped field contain "&" symbol then the group text is displayed as string encoded. For e.g. if the records in the group by column contain "Cat&Dog" then the group by text is displayed as `Cat&amp;Dog`. What I need is to display is Cat&Dog not `"Cat&amp;Dog"` in my GroupBy Header text. Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Thanks
Ram

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that in the SPGridView the grouping is related somehow to the column you are grouping by. I think the property you are looking for is "HtmlEncode" and set that to False if you don't want it to encode automatically.